# Ruby replace backslash with double backslash in a String

Tags: ruby, string, substitution, backslash

I have this little problem that bugs me. I need to double every backslash in a string, for exaple, If have a string `1 \ 2`, I whish to transform it into `1 \\ 2`. I don't see why the code below fails. Can you help? PS. Please don't tell me to split in chars and operate on the list elements then join ;) I need to know if this is a bug in `sub` or if i am missing something. bye

```
irb> s = '1 \\ 2'
irb> puts s
1 \ 2
irb> s.size 
5
irb> s[2]
"\\"
# now i try to do the substitution
irb> s2 = s.sub('\\', '\\'*2)   # or '\\\\'
"1 \\ 2"
irb> s2.size
5
```

Comment: it is a real pity this post is down-voted. Many experienced in several programming languages will fall here. Since this is not what one would expect from a substitution. E.g. in Python, just to name one, `s = "\\" ; s.replace("\\","\\\\")` does what one expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note that `\\` is interpreted as an escape, i.e., a single backslash.
>
> Note also that a string literal consumes backslashes. See string literal for details about string literals.
>
> A back-reference is typically preceded by an additional backslash. For example, if you want to write a back-reference `\&` in replacement with a double-quoted string literal, you need to write `"..\\&.."`.
>
> If you want to write a non-back-reference string `\&` in `replacement`, **you need first to escape the backslash to prevent this method from interpreting it as a back-reference, and then you need to escape the backslashes again to prevent a string literal from consuming them**: `"..\\\\&.."`.

*https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods*

What that means is you need more backslashes:

```rb
>> "1 \\ 2".sub("\\", "\\"*4)
=> "1 \\\\ 2"
# or
>> "1 \\ 2".sub("\\", Regexp.escape("\\\\"))
=> "1 \\\\ 2"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and pointing to the doc ! I was not aware of String.sub back-referencing. Another level of escaping makes sense. More specifically, from the doc `Note that \\ is interpreted as an escape, i.e., a single backslash.` , which doubles the same rule that is applied to read-in the string from literal.

Comment: you can also use a simple string substitution without back-references: `s = "1 \\ 2"; s["\\"] = "\\\\"; s #=> "1 \\\\ 2"` https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/string#method-i-5B-5D-3D

Comment: This is the nicest ! The only issue with it is that it matches just the first occurrence.

Comment: correct, just like `sub` method. i guess you want `gsub`. you can also use block form where extra escaping is not necessary `"1 \\ 2 \\ 3".gsub("\\") { "\\\\" }`

Comment: I would say that definitely for me using `gsub` and `sub` with a String argument and block is THE solution when i want a quick and simple (escape happening only once) string substitution. Thank you !